# Angular web application going into loop after getting Access Denied from ADFS to Keycloak

Tags: angular, saml, keycloak, adfs2.0

I am developing Angular web application which, is integrated with Keycloack (as an identity broker) + ADFS. When I provide a valid user(authenticated and authorized) credentials, I am able to login successfully. But when I provide credentials for Authenticated and Not Authorized user from a web app (i.e. ADFS login page), web application goes into the loop. Keycloack continuously sends the request to the ADFS server.
Below status tag contains in ADFS SAML response:

```
<samlp:Status>
<samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder"><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:RequestDenied"/></samlp:StatusCode>
</samlp:Status>
```

I tried to found Keycloack configuration to handle Access Denied situation.
Also tried to use custom Authenticator for Keycloak. Implemented one microservices as per the link: https://medium.com/@d3l33t/extending-keycloak-spi-with-custom-saml-group-mapper-using-jboss-modules-a6a339641b32 
and deployed jar into "/keycloak/standalone/deployments/" and configured standalone.xml file  with below tag:

```
<spi name="identity-provider-mapper">
<provider name="saml-group-idp-mapper" enabled="true"/>
</spi>
</subsystem>
</profile>
```

I expect Keycloak should redirect to an error page for access denied SAML response. Please suggest how to handle this scenario.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have similar problem